# Rotate mesh about another element?

Tags: rotation, godot, gdscript

I want to have the camera move with a mesh. Foward/backward motion was easy:

```
if (Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_W)):
    self.translation.z -= movement_speed; # relies on camera script to move camera
if (Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_S)):
    self.translation.z += movement_speed;
```

I just put those short blocks on both the camera and the mesh. But I can't figure out how to rotate the mesh about the camera while rotating the camera. If I just rotated the mesh, it would rotate about it's center point and end up unaligned with the camera. In photoshop, you can set anchor points to rotate a layer about a point other than the center. How can I set an anchor point to another element/node in godot?

EDIT:

The solution to rotation was pretty simple. All I had to do was make the camera a child of the mesh I wanted it to follow. But then the camera did not move with the mesh... How do I get the motion to work?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I'm sorry, I literally started using Godot yesterday... how does this work? Can you maybe just write an answer explaining this to me? The documentation is very helpful saying all of: "The translation offset to the transform". Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote my initial comment, I was assuming I was answering an HTML/CSS/Javascript question. - Evidence I need some sleep, as I did not read the question. However, I am relatively familiar with Godot. I will look into finding a "proper" solution for your problem.

Comment: This video might have the answer you are looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kc-zJnRvPUY --- The "anchor point" you are looking for is achieved by adding a spacial node as a child of the mesh (which is used as the camera target), and then making the camera a child of the spacial node. Real time camera updates are done through a physics_process script.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Ha... I thought I remembered that term from somewhere... Thanks for looking in to that. You really didn't need to!

Comment: It's no problem. I get better at coding by helping others. Plus I love the Godot engine, and am always interested in knowing all it's in's and out's.